# Python order of execution of logic check

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my boss came up with this (by accident) after a quick search and replace on the code and opening a Pull Request, where tag is always a string:

```
if "team_" in tag in tag:
```

To my surprise, that actually works! Not really sure why. I was expecting to parse it from left to right and get an error, like this

```
>>> ("team_" in "something") in "something"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bool
```

or even in the worst case, parse it from right to left (which I find it odd, but let's assume it works that way)

```
>>> "team_" in ("something" in "something")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

but what I got instead was

```
>>> "team_" in "something" in "something"
False
>>> 
>>> "some" in "something" in "something"
True
>>>
```

can someone explain to me how/why does that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for the same reason that

```
1 < x < 10
```

works. Python allows comparison operators to be chained, so this is equivalent to

```
1 < x and x < 10
```

By the same logic

```
"team_" in tag in tag
```

is equivalent to

```
"team_" in tag and tag in tag
```

When `tag` is a string, this is effectively equivalent to just `"team_" in tag`, since a string is always in itself. But if `tag` is a list or other container it will usually be false because a container doesn't usually contain an instance of itself (it's possible to make recursive references, e.g. `mylist.append(mylist)`, and then `mylist in mylist` would be true).

Answer (score 2):

You're witnessing *chained comparisons* (a more classic example being something like `a < b < c`)

```
"some" in "something" in "something"
```

is the same as

```
("some" in "something") and ("something" in "something")
```

so it's valid.

But if you protect one side with parentheses,

```
("some" in "something") in "something"
     aka   True         in "something"
```

then you generate a boolean on one side, which explains the error message (the error message is different depending on the side, in the left case it refuses to look for a boolean in a string, and in the right case it refuses to iterate on a boolean)

Yes this natural language stuff is treacherous and can accidentally compile (see a classic issue: [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value))

Comment: Actually, the error would only happen if you put the parentheses on the right, not the left.

Comment: it happens in both cases: `>>> True in "ldldl"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bool`

Comment: Right, I was thinking of `in list`, since a list can contain any type

Comment: not the same error, agreed, but still an error because strings are protected against those hazards